# ESP32 Deep Sleep - BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I want to put the ESP32 into deep sleep and start advertising after.

My problem is that it takes almost 1.3 seconds to init the BLEDevice:

```
BLEDevice::init("DEV1"); // Takes over a second
```

According to the documenation the bluetooth settings are stored in the RTC memory, but I cant find any good examples on how to quickly get the device up again after deep sleep. Is it correct to do a BLEDevice::init after a deep sleep?